# Understanding joins in XQuery

Tags: xml, join, xquery

I have two XML documents that I want to join using XQuery. I know that the data contains some duplicate entries.

test1.xml

```
<marc:collection
    xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <marc:record>
        <marc:leader>01225cam a2200373Mi 4500</marc:leader>
        <marc:controlfield tag="001">5323084</marc:controlfield>
        <marc:datafield
            ind1="1"
            ind2="4"
            tag="245">
            <marc:subfield code="a">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</marc:subfield>             
        </marc:datafield>
    </marc:record>
    <marc:record>
        <marc:leader>01225cam a2200373Mi 4500</marc:leader>
        <marc:controlfield tag="001">5323084</marc:controlfield>
        <marc:datafield
            ind1="1"
            ind2="4"
            tag="245">
            <marc:subfield code="a">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</marc:subfield>             
        </marc:datafield>
    </marc:record>
    <marc:record>
        <marc:leader>00818cam a2200241Mi 4500</marc:leader>
        <marc:controlfield tag="001">6310976</marc:controlfield>
        <marc:datafield
            ind1="0"
            ind2="0"
            tag="245">
            <marc:subfield code="a">Diccionari manual de sinònims i antònims de la llengua catalana /</marc:subfield>             
        </marc:datafield>
    </marc:record>
</marc:collection>
```

test2.xml

```
<root>
    <row>
        <LANGUAGE>cat</LANGUAGE>
        <ITEM_ID>5912416</ITEM_ID>
        <BIB_ID>5323084</BIB_ID>    
        <VENDOR_CODE>MXBKSMX</VENDOR_CODE>
    </row>
    <row>
        <LANGUAGE>cat</LANGUAGE>
        <ITEM_ID>5912416</ITEM_ID>
        <BIB_ID>5323084</BIB_ID>        
        <VENDOR_CODE>PUVILL</VENDOR_CODE>
    </row>
    <row>
        <LANGUAGE>cat</LANGUAGE>
        <ITEM_ID>5935043</ITEM_ID>
        <BIB_ID>6310976</BIB_ID>
        <VENDOR_CODE>PUVILL</VENDOR_CODE>
    </row>
</root>
```

I am trying to do a simple join using the value of `marc:controlfield[@tag = '001']` from `test1.xml` and `BIB_ID` from `test2.xml`.

XQuery

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim";

for $m in doc("test1.xml")/marc:collection/marc:record, 
$r in doc("test2.xml")/root/row[BIB_ID = $m/marc:controlfield[@tag = '001']]

return 
<test n="{$r/ITEM_ID}">{
    $m/marc:datafield[@tag = '245']/marc:subfield[@code = 'a']/string()
}</test>
```

When I run this, I get repeated values for the first two matches:

```
<test n="5912416">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</test>
<test n="5912416">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</test>
<test n="5912416">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</test>
<test n="5912416">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</test>
<test n="5935043">Diccionari manual de sinònims i antònims de la llengua catalana /</test>
```

I can fix this by adding a `group by` clause:

```
for $m in doc("test2.xml")/marc:collection/marc:record, 
$r in doc("test1.xml")/root/row[BIB_ID = $m/marc:controlfield[@tag = '001']]
group by $key := $r/ITEM_ID 

return 
<test c="{$key}">{
    $m/marc:datafield[@tag = '245']/marc:subfield[@code = 'a']/string()
}</test>
```

Result

```
<test c="5912416">Els teleclubs a les illes Balears : Els teleclubs a les illes Balears :</test>
<test c="5935043">Diccionari manual de sinònims i antònims de la llengua catalana /</test
```

But I would like to understand why, in the first case, the duplicate entries are repeated for each `for` clause. Why doesn't the predicate in the second `for` clause filter out the repeated values when the join occurs? And if I did want to preserve the duplicate entries (without the unwanted repetition), what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, similar effect can be observed in SQL JOIN. When the key used for JOIN is not unique, you'll get *cartesian product* of all data with matching keys.

For example in this case, there are 2 `<row>` elements having `BIB_ID` equals `5323084` in the first XML, and there are 2 `<marc:record>` elements matching that value in the second XML. So the result is all possible combination when pairing 2 rows of data against another 2 rows of data (see the illustration*), which results in 4 possible combinations (2 x 2) as you observed in the XQuery result.

[image]

*: <sub>The diagram actually used to illustrate CROSS JOIN in the [source article](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/sql-joins), but the effect is the same.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Many XPath XQuery expressions eliminate duplicate nodes in the sense that the same node does not appear twice in the result, but there are no expressions that eliminate duplicates in the sense that the nodes are deep-equal (all children, descendants, and attributes the same).

My instinct for this problem would be to eliminate duplicates from the input before doing the join, rather than eliminating them from the result.

> "And if I did want to preserve the duplicate entries (without the
>   unwanted repetition), what would be the best approach?"

In my experience, in such situations you usually want a tree structure as the result, rather than a flat result, so you have to throw relational thinking out of the door. You usually end up with an expression something like

```
for $i in $input return
<parent value="{$i/something}">{
  for $j in $anotherInput[$j/xyz = $i/abc] return
    <child value="{$j/something}"> {
      f($i, $j)
    }</child>
}</parent>
```